# C. after using scanf() with the list of allowed characters, can't get the value of the entered character

Tags: c, char, printf

I've found out that you could write the list of characters that are (not)allowed as an input when using `scanf()`.
I need a user to type one of the following letters: `d`, `f`, `r`, `k`, `c`

So what i did is the following, and it works actually exactly the way i want it to. it doesn't let the program go further until one of the allowed letters is eventually pressed:

`scanf ("%[^cfrdk]", &skala);`

after that i want to check which of those five letter was actually entered, and here i get the whole problem. i don't get what exactly happens to the variable `skala` but its value is obviously not the entered letter. as i try to print it, it prints nothing. The switch-case after that also always goes by default.

here is the whole code:

```
    int main()
    {
    char skala;
    float inval,cels, fahr, kelvin, rankine, delis;

    printf("Choose the Skala. Enter:\n`C` for Celsius"
    " \n`F` for Fahrenheit \n`D` for Delisle \n`K` for Kelvin \n`R` for Rankine"
    " \n Enter the letter here —> ");

    scanf ("%[^cfrdk]", &skala);

    getchar();
    //printf("You have entered correctly. %c", &skala); PRINTS NOTHING

    switch (skala){
        case 'c': printf("You've chosen Celsius\n");
        break;
        case 'f': printf("You've chosen Fahrenheit\n");
        break;
        case 'r': printf("You've chosen Rankine\n");
        break;
        case 'd': printf("You've chosen Delisle\n");
        break;
        case 'k': printf("You've chosen Kelvin\n");
        break;
        default:printf("ERROR: wrong input\n");
        break;
    }

    printf ("Enter a value to be converted = ");
    scanf("%f", &inval);

    return 0;
    }`
```

who can explain it what exactly happens to the variable in `scanf` when using the list of allowed characters. And what are the ways of solving the problem?

Comment: I think you may need to review how `%[..]` *works*.  See [the documentation for [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), for multiple reasons why what you have is wrong.

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf`, because unhandled parse error can make your code do all kinds of funny things (even if you manage to avoid invoking Undefined Behavior caused by uninitialized variables).

Comment: Also, enable compiler warnings (google how to do that for your compiler), so that compiler warns you about (most) invalid format strings.

Comment: `scanf ("%[^cfrdk]", &skala);` --A> `scanf ("%[cfrdk]", &skala);`

Comment: The caret says 'any character except'

Comment: @LPs
ok it solved it sort of... now if i enter one of the allowed letters the switch-case works and it is nice. but now when i enter say `p` which is not allowed the program goes further to switch-case. my idea was that i won't let you continue until the correct letter is entered. Should i just use some while loop instead to check the entered value? cause this set of allowed characters does not seem to be the best decision

Comment: @Diana General, sanity-preserving solution to invalid input handling problem in this kind of C program is to read entire line (fgets), then parse it (sscanf) and ask again if line was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The do/while loop will repeat until a letter in the set of valid letters is input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char skala;
    char valid[] = "cfdkr";
    float inval,cels, fahr, kelvin, rankine, delis;
    int result = 0;
    int clean = 0;

    printf("Choose the Skala. Enter:\n`C` for Celsius"
    " \n`F` for Fahrenheit \n`D` for Delisle \n`K` for Kelvin \n`R` for Rankine"
    " \n Enter the letter here —> ");
    do {
        if ( ( result = scanf (" %c", &skala)) != 1) {
            if ( result == EOF) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (strchr ( valid, skala) == NULL) {
            printf ( "enter your choice of %s\n", valid);
            result = 0;
        }
    } while ( result != 1);

    switch (skala){
        case 'c': printf("You've chosen Celsius\n");
        break;
        case 'f': printf("You've chosen Fahrenheit\n");
        break;
        case 'r': printf("You've chosen Rankine\n");
        break;
        case 'd': printf("You've chosen Delisle\n");
        break;
        case 'k': printf("You've chosen Kelvin\n");
        break;
        default:printf("ERROR: wrong input\n");
        break;
    }

    do {
        printf ("Enter a value to be converted = ");
        if ( ( result = scanf("%f", &inval)) != 1) {
            while ( clean = getchar ( )) != '\n') {
                if ( clean == EOF) {
                    fprintf ( stderr, "problem getting input\n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    } while ( result != 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need a user to type one of the following letters: d, f, r, k, c

Code cannot control what the user types.  Code needs to cope with unexpected input.

The below is bad code.  If `scanf()` does encounter some non-`cfrdk`, it will save 1 *or more* of those characters into `skala` and then append a null character.  `skala` being only a `char`, is the wrong type for reading strings - the type expected by `%[]`.  Result: Undefined behavior (UB).

If use does type a `cfrdk`, then `scanf ("%[^cfrdk]", &skala);` will read nothing into `skalla` and return 0.

```
scanf ("%[^cfrdk]", &skala);
```

---

Better to simply read all user input.  Be sure to handle `'\n'`

```
switch (getchar()){
    case 'c': printf("You've chosen Celsius\n");
      break;
    case 'f': printf("You've chosen Fahrenheit\n");
      break;
    case 'r': printf("You've chosen Rankine\n");
      break;
    case 'd': printf("You've chosen Delisle\n");
      break;
    case 'k': printf("You've chosen Kelvin\n");
      break;
    case '\n': // ignore
      break;
    case EOF: // input is closed
      return -1;
    default: printf("ERROR: wrong input\n");
      // break;
}
```

Even better as suggested by [@hyde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221763/c-after-using-scanf-with-the-list-of-allowed-characters-cant-get-the-value/40223099#comment67708827_40221763), read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` and then validate the input.

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
  // Handle End-Of-File or Error
  return -1;
}

char scale[2] = { 0 };
// Check for valid initial character,  additional checks possible
if (sscanf(buf, "%1[cfrdk]") != 1) Handle_Bad_Input(buf);
else {
  switch (scale[0]) {
    ...
```